# Powerbi Desktop: How to filter without having to select each item?

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

I've been searching for a solution, but haven't found anything close.

As you can see from the screenshot, one of the fields in my Powerbi Desktop is `DimCurrency.CurrencyName`. In this example, there are 120 different currencies in `DimCurrency`.

Our end-users usually filter by different currencies, and it's extremely tedious and time-consuming to scroll through the list and check the 40 currencies that will be part of the filter.

Instead of selecting each one individually, is there a way to copy/paste the list into a filter box so that the items in the list are the filter? For example, our list may look something like this: "Euro,Forint,Lek,US Dollar,Won,Shilling"

Also, our endusers are non-technical, so this would need to be done in Powerbi Desktop (no MDX, external tables,  etc). Also, each filter is completely different, so we can't build "templates" that will be reused.

[image]

Comment: Is there any way you can know what these lists of currencies are in advance or is it entirely up to the end-user?

Comment: It’s entirely up to the end-user.

Answer (score 0):

This is possible by using the "[Filter by List](https://blog.pragmaticworks.com/power-bi-custom-visuals-filter-by-list)" custom visual from Pragmatic Works.

Check-out their demo video in the above link - which is the [following video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GdJS25F2Xx8)

Comment: I had seen that option before. The problem is that it used to be in the Power Bi appstore, but it's been removed. Also, the the download link is in a domain with SSL issues.

Comment: The problem is that this goes against company policy. For example, our company blocks any file storage domains, so I get a big, red, ugly warning every time I go to google drive, onedrive, etc.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have any solution for that. But if you're looking for a default feature in PowerBI which allows filtering by list, then I don't think that's available.